# How do I get the index of a number in a list in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

Just heads I'm fairly new to prolog so this might be a bit of a dumb question, but,
Basically what I'm trying to accomplish is to get the index from a natural number, except 0,
e.g.

```
list = [3,0,0,0,0,6]
```

3 has an index of 1 and 6 an index of 6

Thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built-in predicate [nth1/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=nth1/3), as follows:

```
?- nth1(1, [one, two, three], Element).
Element = one.

?- nth1(Index, [one, two, three], two).
Index = 2 ;
false.

?- nth1(Index, [one, two, three, one], one).
Index = 1 ;
Index = 4.

?- nth1(Index, [one, two, three], Element).
Index = 1,
Element = one ;
Index = 2,
Element = two ;
Index = 3,
Element = three.
```

To index from 0 (instead of 1), use [nth0/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=nth0/3).